# What's the difference between 'ask' and 'inquire'? Can I use them interchangeably?

Tags: word-choice, differences, verbs

For example, see the [following reference](http://www.readbookonline.net/readOnLine/22520/):

> Denison was interested, went over to him, and watched the swift, skilful manner in which the thin brown fingers worked.
>
> "Where are you going to fish?" he inquired.
>
> The broad, flat face lit up. "Outside in the dam deep water--sixty, eighty fa'am."

Can I also use "he asked" here? Where are the places I cannot use *ask* instead of *inquire*?

Comment: It may also help to be aware that, depending on your location, _inquire_ may be less appropriate than _enquire_ for your example. In Australia, an _inquiry_ is more of a formal investigation than an _enquiry_, which is simply asking a question. I believe there is no difference between the two in American English, but I'm not sure about British English.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can *ask* that someone perform an action.
When you *inquire* you only request information.
You can *ask* for permission, a favour, or forgiveness, but not *inquire* for them.
They're not interchangeable, *ask* is broader.

Answer (score 6):

In the most basic form, *ask* can be applied to any question and the response may be completely ignored if not required. *Inquire*, on the other hand, implies an eagerness on the part of the former to receive a response.

Answer (score 2):

In American and Australian English, they are interchangeable, but an *inquiry* would be a more formal investigation.

Comment: See my comment to the question; in Australian English, "enquire" would be interchangeable with "ask" only in some circumstances (see @donothingsuccessfully's answer), "inquire" would be even less interchangeable if you will.